# How to search for values from a list in the document - Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

I need to search for documents in 'quentinhas' where the search parameter is the 'diasDaSemana' ....

Something like:

```
  buscarPorDiaDaSemana(diaDaSemana) {
    if (diaDaSemana != "") {
      this.quentinhaCollection = this.afs.collection('quentinhas', ref => {
        console.log(diaDaSemana)

        return ref.where('diasDaSemana', '==', diaDaSemana);
      });
    }
    this.quentinhas = this.quentinhaCollection.snapshotChanges()
      .map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;

          return { id, data };
        });
      });
    return this.quentinhas
  }
```

But this code does not work to search within that list.

Below image of firestore:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your days as an object instead of an array.

Your `diasDaSemana` property would then look like this:

[image: diasDaSemana]

Then you can query them like so:

`ref.where('diasDaSemana.{insertNameOfDayHere}', '==', true)`

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris, I'll follow your logic, sorry for my English, would you have any examples of how you would insert it this way?

Comment: Do you mean how to insert it into the database?

Comment: yes, how to insert in that format you are displayed =)

Comment: You can read that in the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=1#data_types

Comment: Forgiveness Chris, my question was stupid ... I've been working for over 12 hours not for direct reasoning, thanks for the tention =)

Comment: No problem Santos. Happy to help :)